# Sidekiq : how to restart sidekiq when deploying project to server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

Here is my restart script for sidekiq
def restart
  process_list.each do |p|
    process_stop p
    process_start p
  end
end

when i am deploying code to production then this script executes and restarts every process.

But now I want to restart sidekiq as running process shouldn't be affected.

In my case : 
I am sending mails using sidekiq.
for example i am sending 100000 mails and this process is executing. If I am deploying this time. then many mails have already triggered and after restarting they will trigger again.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: def restart
  process_list.each do |p|
    process_stop p
    process_start p
  end
end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each mail should be a separate job.

Comment: I want to wail for restarting sidekiq until worker queue length is zero. Is it possible?